# How to handle Network Calls when there is a Weaker Network connection in android

Tags: java, android, networking

The Problem here is guys that i have an android app which uses Geocoding and makes REST based Network calls, this however works flawlessly when i am using WI-FI, however when i have tried using GPRS network it does well most times but there are instances when it has failed resulting in a force close. How to handle this during situations when the network is weak like making a call again e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

Way too broad of a question, but I'd imagine getting to the bottom of the Force Close would be the first step.